# Method screen has message - Unresolved function or method

Tags: reactjs, testing, webstorm

I am writing tests for React component with @testing-react-library
The code works correctly, but I see the message - Unresolved function or method getByTestId()
[image: screenshot]
How can I fix this problem?

I am using webstorm

Comment: How are you importing `screen`?

Comment: `import { screen } from '@testing-library/react'` 
Here is my import, I repeat that the tests are successful, but webstorm does not accept methods from the screen. @AlexWayne

Comment: it's correctly resolved for me. Is `node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types` folder included in indexing? Does the issue persist after caches invalidation (**File > Invalidate caches, Invalidate and Restart**)?

Comment: Thanks, I did this recommendation but this doesn't help with my problem @lena

Comment: `ctrl+click` on `screen` - where are you taken to?

Comment: node_modules > @testing-library > dom > types > screen.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

After spending 5 hours, Here's what I found

For Me :-

1. I had intel compatible intellij installed on my mac(apple-chip), replaced it with apple chip compatible intellij.
2. Inside setupTest file, I had to add `import '@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest';`

If this doesn't work, Other things worth trying :-

1. Find the issue discussed on intellij support [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000357324-Get-rid-of-Unresolved-function-method-variable-warning-in-Jest-test-files)